# How to avoid using inline functions in React (ES6) for functions that take arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to follow the suggestion in this [react-eslint doc](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) to avoid using inline functions.

I have a div with an `onClick` funciton like so:

```
onClick={ () => this.props.handleClick(some_constant) }
```

This works perfectly fine, however I don't want to have an inline function. When I try to abstract it by following the pattern in the provided link above, I get a setState error that runs infinitely.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this._handleClickWrapper = this.handleClickWrapper.bind(this);
  }

  _handleClickWrapper() {
    // handleClick is a callback passed down from the parent component
    this.props.handleClick(some_constant)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this._handleClickWrapper}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What needs to be done so that I can avoid using inline functions?

**Edit:**

I made a serious typo, but in my code, I have what is currently reflected and it  is still causing the error.

Comment: I find that advice to be extremely hard to take seriously.

Comment: What "setState error that runs infinitely" do you get? I use the pattern you've presented all the time...

Comment: I don't really know React, but my first thought is that `this` doesn't work the same way in arrow functions as in traditional functions.

Comment: `onClick={ this.props.handleClick.bind(this, some_constant) }` ?

Comment: @pawel The correct answer

Comment: @AlanH well not really, the lint rule you have linked to treats inline function and bind as equal offenders. I would'n enforce it if it meant I have to fight the linter instead of being productive unless I have really hit a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 4):

You bound the wrong function to `this`. It should be:

```
this._handleClickWrapper = this._handleClickWrapper.bind(this);
```

This way `_handleClickWrapper` will always be bound to the context of the component.

Comment: I made a big mistake. Thanks for the catch, but that's not the cause of the issue.

Comment: How about passing props? `constructor(props)` and `super(props)`

Answer (score 1):

If you really really really want to follow the jsx-no-bind rule, you can create a new component and pass `someConstant` in as a prop. Then the component can call your callback with the value of `someConstant`:

```
class FooDiv extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>Hello!</div>
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.someConstant);
  }
}
```

Then your `Foo` component can just do this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const someConstant = ...;
    return (
      <FooDiv
        onClick={this.props.handleClick}
        someConstant={someConstant}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Having said that, I would recommend not following `jsx-no-bind` and just use bind or arrow functions in render. If you're worried about performance due to re-renderings caused by using inline functions, check out the [reflective-bind](https://github.com/flexport/reflective-bind) library.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a typo

`this._handleClickWrapper = this.handleClickWrapper.bind(this);`

should be

`this._handleClickWrapper = this._handleClickWrapper.bind(this);`

2. in your constructor you forgot to pass `props` to `super()`

   ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this._handleClickWrapper = this._handleClickWrapper.bind(this);
   }
   ```

**Tipp**: You can avoid binding (and even the constructor) by using arrow functions declaration inside the class (babel-preset-es2016).

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  state = {} // if you need it..

  onClick = () => {
    this.props.handleClick(some_constant)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way you components gets smaller, and easier to read.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

Comment: es6 classes don't autobind

Comment: right, need to include babel-preset-es2016
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es7-property-initializers